# How to use Wordpress with localhost and a preexisting database on another server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost

I've been working on a Wordpress website on my web hosting server. But I wanted to start doing the Wordpress changes locally, while still using the database with all the posts and stuff that's already on the server.

I installed Wordpress on my computer, and had it connect successfully to that database, but going to localhost/website/wp-admin would redirect me to www.site.com/website/wp-admin, and then proceed to do everything on the server again, which I didn't want, and localhost/website would just appear blank.

I tried having Wordpress use a new test_database on the server, and it was happy with that. Wordpress started to run locally, localhost/website wasn't black, while using a database on the server. Even when I wiped out my local Wordpress and reinstalled it connecting to test_database, all the posts remained intact, and Wordpress was still running locally.

How come I was unable to get Wordpress running locally when I tried to connect to the first database?

Comment: If you run locally, but are using **and modifying** data in the live website's database, one could argue that it's not at all different from using the website "on the server" as far as the end result is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the same WordPress database instance on two different URLs. You Can't Do That™. Someplace in the options table is the database's URL. It's used to construct many links in WordPress. That's why you're jumping back to the production server.

You can use a plugin like [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to make a copy of your production web site to use as a staging server, or vice versa.